# How to get the righthand div to fall above the left div in Foundation when collapsing to one column

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm building a site in Zurb's Foundation 4. And I have a row that has two columns. The left column is a paragraph and the right column is an image. When I reduce the browser to mobile dimensions so that the layout will collapse to one column I would like the right div, the image, to be ABOVE the left div, the paragraph, when it transforms to one column.

By default the image is going to fall below the paragraph since the div is later in the order.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foundation has `push` and `pull` classes you can use for this.  In your situation, you would set it up like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-6 push-6 columns">Image</div>
  <div class="large-6 pull-6 columns">Text from paragraph</div>
</div>
```

You can find out more on this by reviewing the docs at http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html and look for '**Source Ordering**'